# Scripting to see if specific process is running as root

Tags: linux, shell, process, scripting

I am currently trying to right a shell script which will allow me to check a process is running with the correct user (root)

I assume I would first have to use ps -efl & grep for the process and if it is running with root = 1 otherwise = 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pgrep , usually available by default in most distros:

```
$ pgrep -a -u root -x geany;echo $?
2794 geany tuesday.txt
0
$ pgrep -a -u root -x gean;echo $?
1
```

Use -x option for exact match, otherwise the process name will be considered as a pattern:

```
$ pgrep -a -u root gean;echo $?
2794 geany tuesday.txt
0
```

Return code ($?) is 0 if process found, 1 if not found.

To keep only the return code and not the process name/info (in case that process is up and running as root) you can redirect pgrep output to /dev/null :

```
$ pgrep -a -u root geany 1>/dev/null;echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the process (e.g. `watch`) :

```
ps -C watch -o uid=
#=> 0
ps -C watch -o ruser=
#=> root
```

If you know the pid :

```
ps -p 4793 -o uid=
0
ps -p 4793 -o ruser=
#=> root
```

You just need to check the `uid` (0 for root) or the username.